# What do we call a child that is born many years after its siblings?

Tags: word-request

In Norwegian we have an Expression called "attpåklatt". That means "Child who is way younger than its older siblings" (like 10 years younger). 
Is there such a Word in English?

Comment: If the pregnancy was unplanned, the parents might refer to such a child as an "afterthought" when in friendly company. The term simply means "an idea that occurred to you afterwards" and it can be used in almost any context.  *Our youngest was an afterthought.*

Comment: Google ["afterthought definition"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=afterthought+definition) ***an idea, thought, or plan that was not originally intended but is thought of at a later time:*** No mention of having babies, or rearing children. It might be used, jokingly, maybe..., but it is not common, and it is not idiomatic unlike its Norwegian counterpart.

Comment: I don't think English has a word for this. It seems to me I've heard the word "surprise" used (or "surprise baby"), but that's used affectionately and figuratively. It's hardly a counterpart to the Norwegian _attpåklatt_.

Comment: I agree, @J.R. Though, sometimes you can get these gaps even with intentional pregnancies, particularly with the prevalence of teen pregnancy in some areas. Having a first child at 16 followed by a child at 26 or later would be a big gap but that child would likely have been planned. :D

Comment: @TRomano I would perceive calling any person an afterthought very negatively. It seems dismissive in the extreme to me. I thought there was some phrase similar to "May September relationship" or "December bride" that described a child born to a couple who seemed to be past their child-bearing years, but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: @Catija - In the circumstance you describe, it's probably the _eldest_ child who would be considered the "surprise baby" ;-)

Comment: Yes, we say in English that the child resulting from an unplanned or unexpected pregnancy is a surprise. We don't have a specific word for it. And afterthought is definitely not a go.

Comment: @ColleenV: As I said, "when in friendly company".  This would hardly be "dismissive in the extreme" but good-humored mild self-deprecation.

Comment: @TRomano You can explain it away, and tell me that I shouldn't see it the way I do, but that doesn't change my perception that it's negative. My point is not that your perception is wrong but simply that it's not universal, and "afterthought" might be more controversial than it seems.

Comment: @ColleenV: Please see the links to the attestations in the comments I've attached to Mari-Lou's answer below. The last one directly addresses the point you're making, that some people would find the term negative. Different strokes for different folks.

Comment: I'll toss my hat into the "no word in English" ring.

Comment: My German-speaking niece some years ago asked at a family gathering what the English word for "Nesthaekchen" was. A moment's silence, then my brother volunteered: "A mistake."
I should add that I am the youngest of my siblings, so this incident stuck in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent of *attpåklatt* that comes to mind is

**baby sister**
**baby brother**

> [**baby sister**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/baby-sister):
>    a younger sister ⇒ *Claire had to dress her baby sister*.

and

> **[baby brother](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/baby-brother)**
>   1. a younger brother
>   2. a newly-born brother ⇒ *She says Dylan adores his baby brother.*

The diminutive and affectionate expression, "baby sister" and "baby brother",  will often continue until adulthood.

Examples taken from the net

> - *I still love him without reserve or restriction to this very day, and he is sixty-two years old. Whether the man likes it or not, he has always been and will always be my baby brother.* ([source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mp2k_5v70OMC&pg=PA12&dq=%22always%20be%20my%20baby%20brother%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ-PWNrKbRAhWFC8AKHau3BGYQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22always%20be%20my%20baby%20brother%22&f=false) 2007)
> - She was no longer a baby, but she will always be my baby sister. ([source](https://books.google.it/books?id=vrrTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22always%20be%20my%20baby%20sister%22&dq=%22always%20be%20my%20baby%20sister%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ7M6qrabRAhUELcAKHQPYBKIQ6AEIHzAB) 1960)
> - Someones kid brother, whom they refer to as a baby, despite their brothers actual age.
>     Older Borther: "so hows my [baby brother](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Baby%20Brother) doing?!"
>     Younger Brother: "Shut up, im 24"
>     (source: Urban Dictionary)

### Observations

Users have pointed out that the term *baby sister/brother* does not express any significant difference in age. And I agree, the expression does not automatically suggest that the elder sibling is between 8 and 12 years older. But it is, in my opinion, the nearest equivalent and like synonyms, equivalents do not always convey the same meanings or subtleties of usage.

### Comments

> - Although to this English speaker, "baby brother/sister" simply means the youngest, and implies nothing about the difference in age - the "baby sibling" could be only one year younger than the others [@stangdon](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114307/what-do-we-call-a-child-that-is-born-many-years-after-its-siblings/114309#comment230240_114309)
> - @stangdon **true,** but the term sticks when the age gap is noticeable. I have a cousin who has two elder brothers, 11 and 12 years older than herself, and she is still called the "baby sister" by them even though she is 46 years old now. It's almost a term of affection. [@Mari-Lou.A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114307/what-do-we-call-a-child-that-is-born-many-years-after-its-siblings/114309#comment230241_114309) (**emphasis** mine)
> - Agree with @stangdon. "Claire" might have several younger siblings so that there would be no long gap between the youngest and the next youngest, and she would still have to dress "her baby sister" [@TRomano](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114307/what-do-we-call-a-child-that-is-born-many-years-after-its-siblings/114309#comment230263_114309)
> - If the parents introduce the baby to a newcomer who doesn't know the family as "this is Claire's baby sister", the newcomer will not infer from that phrase that there are no other siblings in between Claire and the baby. But if the parents say something like "This little one is Marie, our youngest. Marie was an afterthought", the newcomer would infer that there was *a considerable span of years during which it seemed the mother's childbearing was behind her*. There is a gap between Marie and all of the other children. [@Tromano](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114307/what-do-we-call-a-child-that-is-born-many-years-after-its-siblings/114309#comment230281_114309)
> - Downvoted because the age gap is not implied. "Baby sister/brother" just means the youngest child. I know a family where 9 children were born in 10 years. No big age gaps, but the youngest is 'the baby' [@miltonaut](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114307/what-do-we-call-a-child-that-is-born-many-years-after-its-siblings/114309#comment230473_114309)

Comment: Although to this English speaker, "baby brother/sister" simply means the youngest, and implies nothing about the difference in age - the "baby sibling" could be only one year younger than the others.

Comment: @stangdon true, but the term sticks when the age gap is noticeable. I have a cousin who has two elder brothers, 11 and 12 years older than herself, and she is still called the "baby sister" by them even though she is 46 years old now. It's almost a term of affection.

Comment: There is also the phrase "the baby of the family".

Comment: The term "baby sister|brother" does not do justice to the central fact of the question, the long gap during which no siblings were born.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipDEPALYGkg

Comment: If the parents introduce the baby to a newcomer who doesn't know the family as "this is Claire's baby sister", the newcomer will not infer from that phrase that there are no other siblings in between Claire and the baby. But if the parents say something like "This little one is Marie, our youngest. Marie was an afterthought", the newcomer would infer that there was *a considerable span of years during which it seemed the mother's childbearing was behind her*.  There is a gap between Marie and *all* of the  other children.

Comment: I have never heard of anyone calling their newborn as an ["afterthought"](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/201k2u/redditors_who_dont_speak_english_as_a_first/) that is the literal translation of the Norwegian word. I have heard parents call their infant an "accident" in loving terms, but never as an "afterthought" please find references to support your assertion. I have found several which suggest that "baby brother/sister" *can* be used in a similar way by *siblings*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  calling a child an "afterthought" would not be nice, as it implies the child was unplanned and is more or less unwanted.   The more euphemistic way to refer to this is simply as an "unplanned pregnancy", which implies very little other than the lack of planning.

Comment: @Andrew shouldn't your comment be directed at TRomano? He is the one who's saying that the expression can be used: `"This little one is Marie, our youngest. Marie was an afterthought", `

Comment: Examples: [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=HDUsgikBbaoC&pg=PA2&dq=%22along+as+an+afterthought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOq7rgtqbRAhUd0IMKHUOIACQQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22along%20as%20an%20afterthought%22) [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=klfhTe63WiAC&pg=PA30&dq=%22along+as+an+afterthought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOq7rgtqbRAhUd0IMKHUOIACQQ6AEITDAI#v=onepage&q=%22along%20as%20an%20afterthought%22) & [3](https://books.google.com/books?id=l0FQAAAAYAAJ&q=%22along+as+an+afterthought%22&dq=%22along+as+an+afterthought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOq7rgtqbRAhUd0IMKHUOIACQQ6AEIWTAL).

Comment: And I suggest you read my earlier comment `It might be used, jokingly, maybe..., but it is not common, and it is not idiomatic unlike its Norwegian counterpart.` and I stick by what I said. Let us agree to disagree.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm just offering my opinion.  Even if used jokingly, it's not a very nice joke.  But some people do joke like that.

Comment: It is common enough and idiomatic. The term can be used bitterly or harshly or in a completely mild and good-natured way. It all depends on the attitude of the speaker. .. or on the attitude of the listener. Here's an example where it wasn't meant to malign but was understood as such: https://books.google.com/books?id=I5sbBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&dq=%22she+was+an+afterthought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzoKe_u6bRAhUL0YMKHfJrBqIQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22she%20was%20an%20afterthought%22

Comment: Downvoted because the age gap is not implied. "Baby sister/brother" just means the youngest child. I know a family where 9 children were born in 10 years. No big age gaps, but the youngest is 'the baby'.

Comment: @miltonaut that's perfectly fine, I never once suggested it was a perfect fit, I clearly stated that it was the closest I could come up with and I provided some evidence.

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially, babies that are born much later than their siblings, which also possibly implies much older parents are sometimes referred to as

> a surprise
>
> Ingrid was a *surprise* to her parents being 12 years younger than her other siblings.

Since one can imagine the conversation might have been a surprise

> Honey, I have some news(!)...

Answer (score 1):

*"baby of the family"*

1. The youngest member of an immediate family.
2. A member of an immediate family who behaves as, or is treated as though they were the youngest member of a family.

*As the baby of the family, Jack had always been a little spoiled.*

In this sentence, "Jack" could be a mature adult and the phrase may imply some age difference.

Answer (score 0):

Most people would jokingly refer to the child born many years after its siblings (assuming the pregnancy was not planned) as an 'accident.'  Of course, if the baby was planned, then they wouldn't!
I think that's the closest to the Norwegian expression you cited.

Answer (score 0):

The term I have heard used for this is ***[caboose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caboose) baby/child***, from the word for the last, little car in a train. This is specifically used when there is a large age gap between older children and the youngest child. For example:

> ### How To Make The Most Of Age Gaps When A 'Caboose Baby' Comes Along
>
> ([*Chicago Tribune* headline](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1989-10-11/entertainment/8901210662_1_age-differences-child-age-gap))
>
> ---
>
> Of course, one last thing I find about having a third **"caboose" baby** well after the first two . . . ([Gail O'Connor, "Making the Leap to Having a Third Baby, Years After the First Two", *Parents*](http://www.parents.com/blogs/parents-perspective/2015/01/08/the-parents-perspective/the-upside-of-having-a-really-big-age-gap-between-babies/))

This term is probably safer to apply to other people than something like "surprise" or "oops" or "change-of-life" baby, since all of those imply things about the family's private circumstances that might be wrong (and aren't other people's business, anyway).

Answer (score -3):

I think I called a *surprise baby* but when there is a big gap between two children then this called a *caboose baby*.